# Extract data from an variable containing a nested array in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to create a facebook signup.  I am receiving the signed_request from facebook that is being decoded and displayed as the following:

```
Array
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [expires] => 0
    [issued_at] => **********
    [oauth_token] => *******************************************************************************************************************
    [registration] => Array
        (
            [name] => Darren West
            [email] => dwest@madeup.com
            [password] => IJ8sU10lw
        )

    [registration_metadata] => Array
        (
            [fields] => name,email,password
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [country] => us
            [locale] => en_US
        )

    [user_id] => ***************
)
```

I want to add the three fields within the registration array to a hidden form and automatically submit it to another page for saving to the database.

My question is how do I extract the name, email, and password from the registration array and assign them to individual variables.  I used the following, but I don't get a result:

```
print $response['registration']->password;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
neojakey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print $response['registration']['password'];
```